# Angular 1.5.4 Service undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a demo app with AngularJS 1.5.4, based on angular seed, EcmaScript 6 and with a node.js web server.

I'm using component routers as described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router and I'm getting an error on a service when called from the component.

The error is

```
etsy.controller.es6:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: EtsyService is not defined
```

Below is the relevant code

index.html

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bower-angular-router/angular1/angular_1_router.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app.js"></script>
<script src="/components/core/constants.es6"></script>
<script src="/components/etsy/etsy.service.es6"></script>
<script src="/components/etsy/etsy.controller.es6"></script>
```

etsy.service.es6

```
(function () {
'use strict'

// variables here ...

class EtsyService {
    constructor($http) {
        _http.set(this, $http);
    }

    // methods here ...

    static etsyServiceFactory($http) {
        return new EtsyService($http);
    }
}

angular
    .module('myApp.etsy')
    .factory('EtsyService', EtsyService.etsyServiceFactory);
})();
```

etsy.controller.es6

```
(function () {
'use strict';

class EtsyController {
    constructor($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Hi from the $scope';
    }
}

angular
    .module('myApp.etsy', [])

    .service('etsyService', EtsyService)

    .component('etsy', {
        templateUrl: 'components/etsy/etsy.html',
        controller: EtsyController
    });
})();
```

I've been googling this for a while now but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `.module('myApp.etsy', [])` from controller, basically that is reinitializing your module

Comment: I tried @PankajParkar but I get the same error

Comment: may I know why you are creating `EtsyService` again inside `etsy.controller.es6`, as its already created there in `etsy.service.es6`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function for EtsyService in your etsy.controller.es6 file within the IIFE. You can look how the guide implements heroes.js and crisis.js for a concrete example. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router

Comment: thanks Eric, that is surely a solution but is there any way to reference the Service without using a function? It seems really redundant otherwise

Comment: You can use dependency injection to pass your service around https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling in that order (servicer and controller), then you are overriding the module by creating a new one:

```
angular
    .module('myApp.etsy')// <--------- getting a module
    .factory('EtsyService', EtsyService.etsyServiceFactory);

angular
    .module('myApp.etsy', [])//<--------------- creating a new module

    .service('etsyService', EtsyService)
```

Comment: I changed as you suggest, but I still get the same error :(

Answer (score -1):

Try changing name file to EtsyService.js, this should work.

Comment: Why should this be relevant? According to the style guide, the name suggested is feature.type.js (ref: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y121)